# Magento Product Image Cache - Background colour issue

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

Seeing an odd issue with cached Magento product images.

Once images are uploaded and cached, some end up having their background colour replaced with what looks like a sampled colour from the image itself.

I cannot work out why this is happening. Has anyone had this issue before?

[image: uploaded image]

[image: cached image]

Comment: Maybe... the servers image processing system imagick or something like that. see: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174108/magento-2-image-processing-settings-gd2-v-s-imagemagick

Comment: Yes, default is to use GD2 which seemed to be causing the problem. Using imagick fixed the issue thank you.